# Java @Override and overloading from a point of view PHP Classes

Tags: java, php

I am trying to rewrite Java code to PHP (for a educational reasons) and I can not understand what `@Override` in combination with overloading means.

The problematic code is located [here](https://github.com/daniel-lobo/Sokoban/blob/master/src/backend/Floor.java#L36). On highlighted line (36) we have first definition of `setContent` method, on line 48 the method is declared again (obviously overloaded) but this time is has the `@Override` statement. I more or less understand what the code means but the confusing thing for me is the fact that only one method is provided with `@Override`.

Does `@Override` change anyhow the behaviour of this code or should I just skip the thing and assume that it is one overloaded method which could be represented in PHP like

```
 public function setContent(
       movable $content,
       $boxActualPlace = null,
       cardinal $cardinal = null
 )
```

Comment: `@Override` is a compiler annotation which tells the compiler that you are attempting to override a method from a parent class.  The compiler can generate an error if their is no matching method in the class hierarchy and is generally used to find mistakes a developer might make, with the naming of the method or it's formal arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you remove `@Override` annotation, it won't change the method behavior in any way. On the other hand, if you add this annotation to the method that is not inherited (from parent class) or implemented (from interface), you will get an error.

Comment: Thanks! Just for the sake of understanding, why only one of those two methods is marked with this annotation?

Comment: No reason really, doesn't make a difference. The programmer probably just left it out by accident or forgot to remove the other one.